# Parallel Processing in python to fill a dictionary with the value as a dictionary(nested)

Tags: python, dictionary, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have multiple links(URL's) in a CSV file and I would like to use these URL's to extract/scrape data and store it in a dictionary format.

To facilitate this, I have developed a function that takes in the URL as the input and returns a dictionary as an output.

Ex:

```
def site_details(URL):

    site_dict = {}
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    site_dict['Date_created'] = soup.find('div', attrs={"class":"date" })
    site_dict['visits'] = soup.find('div', attrs={"class":"visits" })
    return(site_dict)
```

Now I would like to process parallel all the URL's and store them in another dictionary which can later be converted in a CSV file.

So far I have tried the following:

```
from multiprocess import Process, Manager
def f(d, x):
    d[x] = site_details(df["Subject_link"][x])
    return d

manager = Manager()
d = manager.dict()
job = [Process(target=f, args=(d, i)) for i in range(5)]

_ = [p.start() for p in job]
_ = [p.join() for p in job]
print(d)
```

The issue is that I am getting an empty list as a result

I would like an output like this:

```
d = {
      1:{date_created : '22/1/2014',visits:490}
      2:{date_created : '23/1/2014',visits:480}
      3:{date_created : '24/1/2014',visits:470}
    }
```

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

This code, using **`multiprocessing`** module works as expected.
This code, using **`multiprocess`** from Mike McKearns should either.

Not working?

a) Check the presence of the **`dill`** module, it is a pre-requisite for `multiprocess` to work.

b) Re-run the code below.

c) Adapt this working template as you wish, yet do resist not to return any value(s), but rather store it/them into instance variable(s) managed by a **`Manager`**-instance, best using the `Manager` as a context-manager using `with Manager as myNewContextManagerForThisLimitedScopeOfUse:` clause

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager                            # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62130801/parallel-processing-in-python-to-fill-a-dictionary-with-the-value-as-a-dictionar
import os

def f( d, l, i ):
    d[0]    = '1'
    d['2']  =  2
    d[0.25] = None
    d[1] = { "date_created": '22/1/2014', "visits": 490, "os.getpid()": os.getpid() }
    d[2] = { "date_created": '23/1/2014', "visits": 480, "os.getpid()": os.getpid() }
    d[3] = { "date_created": '24/1/2014', "visits": 470, "os.getpid()": os.getpid() }
    d[99 + 100 * ( i + 1 )] = os.getpid()
    l.reverse()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print( "The __main__ in PID::", os.getpid() )
    with Manager() as myDemoMANAGER:
        d = myDemoMANAGER.dict()
        l = myDemoMANAGER.list( range( 10 ) )

        # p = Process( target = f, args = ( d, l ) )
        # 
        # p.start()
        # p.join()
        
        jobs = [ Process( target = f, args = ( d, l, i ) ) for i in range( 5 ) ]
        _    = [ p.start() for p in jobs ]
        _    = [ p.join()  for p in jobs ]
        
        
        print( "The dict instance is: ", d )
        print( "The list instance is: ", l )
        print( "\nQ.E.D." )

'''
(py3) Tue Jun 02 13:49:27 $ python StackOverflow_py3_Multiprocess.py

The __main__ in PID:: 19595
The dict instance is:  { 0: '1',
                         0.25: None,
                         1: { 'date_created': '22/1/2014', 'visits': 490, 'os.getpid()': 19610 },
                         2: { 'date_created': '23/1/2014', 'visits': 480, 'os.getpid()': 19607 },
                         3: { 'date_created': '24/1/2014', 'visits': 470, 'os.getpid()': 19607 },
                         199: 19604,
                         299: 19605,
                         399: 19607,
                         499: 19609,
                         599: 19610,
                        '2': 2
                         }
The list instance is:  [ 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 ]

Q.E.D.

'''
```

### A minor remark on modifying managed objects internal details:

Documentation explicitly warns about modifying v/s assigning v/s re-assigning managed referents:

<sub>*If standard (non-proxy) [**`list`**](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#list) or [**`dict`**](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dict) objects are contained in a referent, modifications to those mutable values will not be propagated through the [manager](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) because the proxy has no way of knowing when the values contained within are modified. However, storing a value in a container proxy (which triggers a **`__setitem__`** on the proxy object) does propagate through the [manager](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) and so to effectively modify such an item, one could re-assign the modified value to the container proxy*</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the help mate!

I figured out what my initial problem was. When I am running the code in a Windows environment the code doesn't work, but when I use a Linux env (using VM on windows), it works fine.

Do you have any idea why it occurs, I am looking at different answers online but can't really find it

Comment: Sure, there is a huge difference in the default ( un-available for Win class of O/S-es ) `multiprocessing`-"backend" engine `{ spawn | loky | ... }`. Do not hesitate to read the documentation for all relevant details on their system properties and what they mean for using the `multiprocessing` processes.